# How to access iTunes library from iOS device via HomeSharing when Mac is sleeping?

Tags: itunes, home-sharing

I have stored my iTunes library on my MacBook and activated home sharing. If I now want to stream some music to my iPad, I can do so from within the Music app. If I like to remotely control my MacBooks library I can do so via Apple Remote app. But what if my MacBook is asleep? After closing it and waiting for several minutes I cannot see the library any more. How can I access my library after the MacBook went to sleep? Would I need an additional app to wake my MacBook over WLAN or is it somehow build in and I just need to set something in the preferences?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking to see if 'wake for network access' is checked in your energy saver preferences:

[image]

Comment: Had it already checked, forget to mention it. Should it work then?

Comment: Checked it now multiple times. It isn't working. After a few minutes, the music App doesn't find the library any more.